# lighttpd with zip extension

Tags: php, zip, lighttpd

I wanted to optmize a project i have by trying out lighttpd instead of apache2 on a Raspberry Pi, but noticed that my php code handling zip files no longer worked because the Zip module for PHP doesnt seem to be loaded or installed. At least not by what i can see with `phpinfo();`.

I've tried writting `lighttpd-enable-mod zip` in my command line, but all i get from that is a `Ignoring unknown module: zip`.

How can i enable or install this module?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, and it was simpler than i was afraid off

When i first installed lighttpd and PHP7 i just didnt include the module that i needed. So it was as simple as just running the following command

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` which then set it all up, and it is now working